# Word inside brackets not working in python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to get all the test case list from a file.
Eg. `void DTC_SetHighBitRate_001()`.

```
re.findall("void S?[DS]TC_.+\(\)", testCaseFile)
```

But now, few test cases are modified like this,

```
void DTC_SetHighBitRate_001(void) 
void DTC_SetHighBitRate_001(Void)
```

I tried to use regular expression like this:

```
re.findall("void S?[DS]TC_.+\([vV]oid)*(\)", testCaseFile)
```

But this did not work. I want to allow ONLY `'void'` or `'Void'` inside the brackets. How can i do that?

EDIT: Sorry to mention that, even if 'void' is not present, it should allow.

1. Empty paranthesis - ()
2. void
3. Void

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you an improved version :

```
re.findall("void S?[DS]TC_.+\([vV]oid\)", testCaseFile)
```

This will find only the occurrences with void (notice the `*` removed)

```
re.findall("void S?[DS]TC_.+\(([vV]oid)?\)", testCaseFile)
```

This will find all the cases: just empty parentheses and with `void`.

Comment: Only one opening of square bracket, but two close is intentional?

Comment: Please see edit - I want to allow empty parenthesis too. Sorry I missed to mention that.

Comment: @shri I understand, this is the purpose of the second line in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. I am using python 3.3.2. Does this matter?

Comment: the expression .* allows any charactor inside paranthesis. If that works, why ([vV]oid)? is not working!

Comment: Have you tried to use raw strings? `re.findall(r"void S?[DS]TC_.+\(([vV]oid)?\)", testCaseFile)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get ...(void) or ...(Void) terms only.Try this

```
re.findall("void S?[DS]TC_.+\([vV]oid]*\)", testCaseFile)
```

Comment: this matches `void DTC_     (void]]]]]]]]]])`

Comment: that may matches others too. But OP didnt provide much data.Just tested simply :)

Comment: Yes, but why did you put `]*`? That doesn't make sense.